# GET - Changing image based on a parameter passed onto url

Tags: html, web-services, get

I recently saw a website that changed a div's background image based on a parameter passed onto a url.

Something that goes like this: http://website.com/image.jpg?p=100

Basically when value of p is from 0 to 100 it shows an image and another one when it exceeds 100. Was wondering how was this achieved. Was there conditional statements involved? Thank you!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Which technologies are used on the server side? It could be done with conditional statements on server or client side

Comment: Probably client side since they were using site builders that doesn't support server side scripting.

Comment: Well, that still doesn't narrow it down much. For example, if apache was used to serve this, it can be done using apache configuration, without needing a script.

Comment: Grab the image url from that website - enter it directly into a browser, see if you get an image.  Now change the p value in the url to something else and reload - do you get a different image?  If so, it's using server-side scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it probably includes a conditional statement. They retrieve the value of the parameter, compare it with a limit value and decide what image should be displayed.

Nothing magical

But, as Vasan says, without more information about the technologies they used, we can't say more.

Comment: If it was client side. Could you give me an idea on how it's done like javascript wise? Cause I know how to retrieve and return results on a web page but based on the link it's not a page. Thanks!